# How does the logic board know the buttons have been depressed on the Philips ACC2330 foot pedal?

Tags: usb-device, input

Unlike other input devices like an Xbox controller, that has the buttons
physically mounted to the logic board, this foot pedal's logic board has
absolutely no apparent connection to the buttons. How is the communication
done? I can't easily take the thing further apart.

### Bottom

[image]

### Bottom Plate Removed

[image]

### Logic Board, Top Left

[image]

### Logic Board, Top Middle

[image]

### Logic Board, Top Right

[image]

### Logic Board, Bottom Left

[image]

### Logic Board, Bottom Middle

[image]

### Logic Board, Bottom Right

[image]

Comment: Probably contacts on the board and conductive strips on the pedals, but your images are too blurry, disorganized, and incomplete to say for sure. I can't even tell which images are from the top or the bottom portions of the pedal assembly.

Comment: There appear to be six integrated circuits on the board. Those could be hall-effect sensors. Hard to tell from the photos.

Comment: Read the product details on the Philips web site: "Robust pedals and non-wearing magnetic contact switches that are built to last". Therefore, Hall-effect sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [hall-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor) sensors. Check where the pedals meet the logic board, and where those ICs are, there should be magnets on the pedal side.

Comment: They probably are. I can't easily open the pedal side to check for magnets.

Comment: A paperclip or other ferrous object could be used to 'detect' a magnet ;)